# Appropriate to say "Nice to meet you" over a phone interview?

Tags: interview

I have a phone interview for a tenure-track position. It's always awkward because you want to say "Nice to meet you, Prof. X" but it sounds so weird. What would be the alternative? You wouldn't just want to say "Hi Prof. X". Would you?

Comment: Interviewing can be very stressful but you are certainly overthinking this and you are meeting them just over the phone. You may not want to say something along the lines of "Good to see you" though. Try to relax they won't remember your greeting even a minute later unless it was very out of.the ordinary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are surely plenty of alternatives.  "It's a pleasure to speak with you."  "Thanks for taking the time to speak with me."  And so on.

However, even if you do say "Nice to meet you", the most that will happen is someone will say "Though I guess we're not really meeting, are we?  Ha-ha-ha."  And you'll say "I guess not, ha-ha-ha" and chuckle politely for about half a second, and then move on.  Nobody will care or remember, and it will have no effect on the outcome of the interview.

Answer (score 0):

Nate [identifies](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/141854/22768) a typical three-way exchange: One party says, "*Nice to meet you*," the other says, "*Though I guess we're not really meeting, are we? Ha-ha-ha*," and you conclude, "*I guess not, ha-ha-ha*." This can be avoided with a phrase such as:

> Nice to virtually meet you.

However, as Nate also notes:

> Nobody will care or remember, and it will have no effect on the outcome of the interview.

**There's no need to plan for the mundane, focus on selling yourself.**